# logout from that browser when click on Facebook logout button

Tags: asp.net, facebook, c#-4.0

I have integrated facebook in my asp.net website and login from code behind.I took an imagebutton and execute code on its onclick event.

**When i click logout ,its logout from my website , but still login in facebook in that browser.
Can any one tell me about Facebook  logout code  ?**

Login Code is something like:-

```
protected void fbimgbtn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
   var root = "http://" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
   string path = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=abcdefgh&redirect_uri=" + root + "/User/Loggingin.aspx";
   path += "&scope=email,publish_stream,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_location,user_hometown,user_work_history&response_type=token";
   Response.Redirect(path);
}
```

Please help me out..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use:

```
https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&confirm=1&next=REDIRECT
```

Using the appropiate access token required & your redirect.

Otherwise if you are using FB Connect then just call:

```
FB.Connect.logout(doOnUserLogout()); return(false);
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan 
I used this code
https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&confirm=1&next=REDIRECT

and its work....